# Как создать иерархию конструкторов объектов в JavaScript?

Tags: ооп, наследование, javascript

Другими словами иерархию "классов"?
Мне нужно создать супер класс и от него наследовать еще 3-4.
Как правильно сделать наследование?

Comment: Не совсем в тему, но взгляните на http://coffeescript.org/ там, кроме прочих удобств, и для классов сахар есть.

Comment: @cranx я бы даже сказал - вообще не в тему :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, следует зацепиться за [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120193/). Там показан пример наследования и пара ссылок на дополнительные ресурсы.

Comment: Спасибо за линк. Закрепил знания, потому-как уже много прочел по этой теме.